# Is it possible to dynamic set menu items in a wxMenu?

Tags: wxwidgets

Hi: I have in a wxFrame a menubar with this wxMenus: File|Edit|Personal. During the frame creation the wxMenu **Personal** has two wxMenuItems (Information and Need Help), which tells the user that must fill the form and help abou how to fill it. After the user fills the form with personal information, the menu is populated with new items: send, clear, check and remove, deleting/removing the previous ones... At this point I manage to trap the event, like this:

```
Bind (wxEVT_MENU_OPEN, &MyFrame::processMenuPersonal, this);
// the method
void MyFrame::processMenuPersonal (wxMenuEvent& event) {
    wxMenu *menu = event.GetMenu ();
    wxMenuItem *item = menu->FindItem (IDM_PERSONAL_EMPTY);
    if (item) {
        // here I want to dynamic add items and remove the current ones
    }
}
```

Any ideas about how to do this?

Comment: There are some code examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28183885/4326278. Note the way you identify the menu that is being opened. Also, are you sure you need to handle this in `wxEVT_MENU_OPEN`? It seems to be a change that happens as a result of a specific user action; I would do it at that specific time (the successful completion of the form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just append as submenu and treat it like any conditional statement. Here is a sample

```
void MyFrame::processMenuPersonal (wxMenuEvent& event) {
    wxMenu *menu = event.GetMenu ();
    wxMenu *item = menu->GetMenu(YOUR_MENU_INDEX);
    menu->AppendSubMenu(item, wxT("User Items"));
    if (YouConditionHere) {
        item->Append(wxID_ANY, "Item 1")
        item->Append(wxID_ANY, "Item 2")
        item->Append(wxID_ANY, "Item 3")
    }
}
```

Note that Items 1,2,3 are the information you want to append after processing your data (in your case deleting old entries)